# Add sequential numbers within a div container with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to add sequential IDs to all divs within a parent container so it looks like this.

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="id1">content</div>
  <div id="id2">content</div>
  <div id="id3">content</div>
</div>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="id1">content</div>
  <div id="id2">content</div>
  <div id="id3">content</div>
</div>
```

Currently it is looking like this:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="id1">content</div>
  <div id="id2">content</div>
  <div id="id3">content</div>
</div>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="id4">content</div>
  <div id="id5">content</div>
  <div id="id6">content</div>
</div>
```

This is my code:

```
 $("#parent").children().each(function(i){
        $(this).attr("id","id" + (i+1));
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, note that your initial HTML is invalid as you cannot have multiple elements with the same `#parent` id.

Assuming that's just a typo in the question, then you can do what you require by looping through the `.parent` divs separately, then using `find()` within that to iterate through the child `div`. Note that you can use an implicit loop over the children by providing a function to `prop()` which accepts the current `index` as an argument.

```js
$('.parent').each((_, el) => $(el).find('div').prop('id', i => `id${i + 1}`));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div>content</div>
  <div>content</div>
  <div>content</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div>content</div>
  <div>content</div>
  <div>content</div>
</div>
```